# Webscrapping through microsoft login

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to create a website where I can put my school login and get my grades.
I am doing the code with Python. When I do it with the cookies everything works well.
However, I cannot do it with the login when I try to go through the Microsoft login.

I read somewhere that it is because the page uses javascript. Reportedly, selenium should work.
But I don't understand how to integrate it into a website because it needs a web driver.

So, my question is: How can I pass through the Microsoft login?
And, would it work better using javascript instead of Python?

This is the link to my school's website where the grades are: https://aurion.ieseg.fr/